# nodemon app crashed after logging in with false credentials

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt, bcrypt, nodemon

if i put bad credentials that are different then information in the databse , i got this error :

`
node:internal/process/promises:246
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:363:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:574:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Chadi Seif\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Chadi Seif\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Chadi Seif\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Chadi Seif\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
at exports.loginAdmin (C:\Users\Chadi Seif\Desktop\testdelete\test2\controllers\admin.js:58:21)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
`

here is my code

````
exports.loginAdmin = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!(email && password)) {
      res.status(400).send({ error: [{ msg: " inputs are required" }] });
    }
    const userfound = await Admin.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!userfound) {
      res.status(400).send({ error: [{ msg: "bad credentials" }] });
    }
    //Compare passwords :
    const compare = await bcrypt.compare(password, userfound.password);
    if (compare) {
      token = jwt.sign({ id: userfound._id }, process.env.TOKEN_KEY, {
        expiresIn: "1days",
      });
      res.status(201).send({ msg: "Happy to see you", userfound, token });
    } else {
      res.status(503).send({ error: [{ msg: "bad credentials" }] });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send({ error: [{ msg: error }] });
  }
};```


please  i need your help community !
````

Answer (score 0):

The error means that thing before that code have already returned some headers/content back to the browser and when you try to set a new status code you get this error.

So, do examine your request pipeline or look in the browser what has already been sent?

also

You should not return a **503** status here

```
res.status(**503**).send({ error: [{ msg: "bad credentials" }] });",
```

typo?

Answer (score 0):

This error throw because you donnot have a return in your function. just put `res.status(...).send(...)` doest not end your function execution. by this way, your function try to set header for sending response every time where we have `res.status(...).send(...)`

So, to fix that, you should `return` response at any time you want to send back response to client like this:

```
 return res.status(400).send({ error: [{ msg: " inputs are required" }] });
```

Your code should be like

```js
exports.loginAdmin = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!(email && password)) {
      return res.status(400).send({ error: [{ msg: " inputs are required" }] });
    }
    const userfound = await Admin.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!userfound) {
      return res.status(400).send({ error: [{ msg: "bad credentials" }] });
    }
    //Compare passwords :
    const compare = await bcrypt.compare(password, userfound.password);
    if (compare) {
      token = jwt.sign({ id: userfound._id }, process.env.TOKEN_KEY, {
        expiresIn: "1days",
      });
      return res.status(201).send({ msg: "Happy to see you", userfound, token });
    } else {
     return res.status(503).send({ error: [{ msg: "bad credentials" }] });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(400).send({ error: [{ msg: error }] });
  }
};`
```

Comment: thank you very much !!

Comment: Yeah @Seif-Ch! Please you can vote for my answer :-)

Comment: Yeah, @Seif-Ch! Please you can vote for my answer since it was usefull :-)

Comment: i am still new to stack overflow i can't vote

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot that constraint -:)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply , i found the answer ... the problem was related to the response sent here :

`if (!userfound) { res.status(400).send({ error: [{ msg: "bad credentials" }] }); }`

because when catching error the response is sent for the second time , and that crashes the Server

Comment: dont forget to use return keyword